# using dblink integrity constraint violated error

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I am trying to insert the data to tables from a remote database using dblink. The first insertion into text_content table didnot happen/ commit didnt happen and then i am trying to insert into the translations table.

```
declare
  v_TextContent_Id NUMBER(19);
begin
    SELECT TEXT_CONTENT_SEQ.NEXTVAL@DBLINK1
    INTO v_TextContent_Id FROM DUAL;  
    --
     INSERT INTO TEXT_CONTENT@DBLINK1 (ID,TEXT_CONTENT_ID)
     VALUES(v_TextContent_Id,CONCAT(u'TextContent_',v_TextContent_Id));  
    dbms_output.put_line('v_TextContent_Id = ' || v_TextContent_Id);
     
  ----- here i need to perform a commit and this is not happening because of this  i get foreign key violation error. 

    INSERT INTO TRANSLATIONS@DBLINK1 (TEXT_CONTENT_ID,LANGUAGE_ID,TRANSLATION)
    VALUES(v_TextContent_Id,1,u'MobileAppD');
end;
```

Is it possible to perform multiple commit. I can see from some of the questions here says multiple commit not allowed. Can some one help me to solve this

Comment: Not committing is not the cause of an FK error. When you get an FK violation, you need look look at (and provide for us) the full error message, which will have the name of the FK constraint. Then look at what table that FK constraint is on (query `all_constraints`) and what columns it is on (`all_cons_columns`) and what parent columns it is pointing to (`all_cons_columns` for the constraint specified by `all_constraints.r_constraint_name`). Then figure out how you are inserting a child row without a corresponding parent row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to perform multiple commit.

Yes. But it is often bad practice as multiple `COMMIT`s will prevent you from `ROLLBACK` the entire transaction so you can get the situation where half the business logic has been carried out and saved with `COMMIT` and then the second half fails but you cannot undo the first half as it has been `COMMIT`ted and your database ends up in an unexpected state.

That does not mean that you cannot (or should not) use multiple `COMMIT`s; just that if you find yourself using `COMMIT` multiple times (or at the end of every procedure) then you should step back and look closely at what you are doing and verify the appropriateness of your behaviour.

> here i need to perform a commit and this is not happening because of this  i get foreign key violation error.

You will not get an error for a foreign key not found if the referenced data was inserted in the same session and is uncommitted. You will only get a foreign key not found exception if:

1. the data does not exist; or
2. was inserted in a different session and has not been committed in that session (even if it is the same user).

---

Are you sure that you are not inserting the wrong value? As `TRANSLATIONS` has the column name `TEXT_CONTENT_ID` and when you inserted the value into the `TEXT_CONTENT` table for that column it had the value `'TextContent_' || v_TextContent_Id` and not `v_TextContent_Id`:

```sql
declare
  v_TextContent_Id NUMBER(19);
begin
  SELECT TEXT_CONTENT_SEQ.NEXTVAL@DBLINK1
  INTO   v_TextContent_Id
  FROM   DUAL;  

  INSERT INTO TEXT_CONTENT@DBLINK1 (ID,TEXT_CONTENT_ID)
  VALUES(v_TextContent_Id, u'TextContent_' || v_TextContent_Id);  

  dbms_output.put_line('v_TextContent_Id = ' || v_TextContent_Id);
     
  INSERT INTO TRANSLATIONS@DBLINK1 (
    TEXT_CONTENT_ID,
    LANGUAGE_ID,
    TRANSLATION
  ) VALUES (
    u'TextContent_' || v_TextContent_Id,          -- ensure the correct prefix.
    1,
    u'MobileAppD'
  );
end;
/
```

Which then leads to the question, why is it necessary to add the prefix `TextContent_`? If that is a constant value then it adds little-to-no benefit and you could omit it on both sides of the referential constraint and nothing will change (other than your code will not be littered with "magic" strings and you do not need to store quite as large strings).